# How to remove a CSS class from an element because of the devices screen width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwsome icons for my website like this:

```html
<i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x social-icon" title="Instagram"></i>
<i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x social-icon" title="YouTube"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x social-icon" title="Twitter"></i>
```

As you can see I'm using "fa-2x" which makes the icon twice the size.
I want the icons to get smaller when the screen of the user is thinner than 400px. I have tried using CSS media-queries like that:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .social-icon {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
}
```

But FontAwsome icons don't support this, so I want to remove the "fa-2x" class from every icon when the screen is 400px wide or less.

I don't know if this is possible with CSS or if I need to use JavaScript, but I'm new to both so I'd be nice if you'd explain precisely how it's ideally done.

Comment: It's an icon in the `:before` pseudo element, so fa-2x is changing `font-size` to 2em not height/width. If you replace your height/width with something like `font-size: 5em` on your existing query it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following what they state in their docs

> Icons inherit the font-size of their parent container

you could wrap your icons in a container an controll the font size their depending on the screen size:

```css
.fontsize {
  font-size: 24px; // or use em for relative sizing
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .fontsize {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="fontsize">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x social-icon" title="Instagram"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x social-icon" title="YouTube"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x social-icon" title="Twitter"></i>
</div>
```

or change your original try to `font-size` instead of width/heigth:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .social-icon {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/js/all.js"></script>
<i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x social-icon" title="Instagram"></i>
<i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x social-icon" title="YouTube"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x social-icon" title="Twitter"></i>
```

The solutions above would be used preferably but if you want/need a JS solution:

```js
let mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 400px)');

if (mql.matches) {

  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('social-icon');
  [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("fa-2x");
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/js/all.js"></script>
<i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x social-icon" title="Instagram"></i>
<i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x social-icon" title="YouTube"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x social-icon" title="Twitter"></i>
```

The above works only onload of the page, not if the size changes after loading. For that you would need to listen to the `resize` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .social-icon, .fa-2x {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
}
```

When you try to change the width by using `.social-icon` it gets overwritten by the `.fa-2x`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have two separate icons, you could definitely just have some CSS Logic in place that's something like this:

```
  @media only screen and (max-width:400px){
    .social_icon_big{ display: none; }
    .social_icon_small{ display: block; }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width:400px){
    .social_icon_big{ display: block; }
    .social_icon_small{ display: none; }
  }
```

You'd just have to tag them both with the appropriate classes =]

Comment: Adding another icon to my html code would destroy the structure but otherwise this is a soloution I haven't even thought of